# How to convert an enum from another enum in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, enums

I have an enum in the main repo:

```
enum class PilotType {
    REMOVABLE,
    FIXED
}
```

And I have another enum in another repo that is imported:

```
enum class PilotTypeDto {
    REMOVABLE,
    FIXED
}
```

In a class in my main repo I need to build this object:
(pilotType is of type PilotType)
(pilotTypeDto is of type PilotTypeDto)

```
return Pilot(
    ... = ...
    pilotType = pilotTypeDto
    ... = ...
)
```

I need to convert pilotTypeDto to a pilotType.

I started building an extension function but it does not seem to let me create an enum:

```
fun pilotType(pilotTypeDto: PilotTypeDto): PilotType {
    return PilotType(
        ...                       // this does not work
    )
}
```

Comment: Don't know about Kotlin, but in Java you could use `pilotType = PilotType.valueOf(pilotTypeDto.name())`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can write this:

```
fun pilotType(pilotTypeDto: PilotTypeDto): PilotType =
    when (pilotTypeDto) {
        PilotTypeDto.REMOVABLE -> PilotType.REMOVABLE
        PilotTypeDto.FIXED -> PilotType.FIXED
    }
```

But as extension you could write this:

```
fun PilotTypeDto.toPilotType() = when (this) {
    PilotTypeDto.REMOVABLE -> PilotType.REMOVABLE
    PilotTypeDto.FIXED -> PilotType.FIXED
}
```

or make it part of the enum by writing this

```
enum class PilotTypeDto {
    REMOVABLE,
    FIXED;

    fun toPilotType() = when (this) {
        REMOVABLE -> PilotType.REMOVABLE
        FIXED -> PilotType.FIXED
    }
}
```

Comment: This would usually be written as an extension function `PilotTypeDto.toPilotType()`

Comment: @Joffrey true, but I was going with the function signature of OP

Comment: I see. It might be worth mentioning the idiomatic way too for posterity :)

Comment: That's not an extension function, that's a member method, though. It implies modifying the original enum type, which may not be possible. Extensions for this are more common and more versatile

Comment: @Joffrey oops you're right. fixed it (I hope)

Comment: Accepted your answer thank you @Ivo!

Comment: @Joffrey, are there any advantages to using extension functions compared to the "non-extension" way (pilotType(pilotTypeDto: PilotTypeDto))?

Comment: Well first there is simply no other option if you don't control the enum class yourself (if it's from a 3rd party library). Then there is the advantage that the extension can live in another module, which helps limit the dependencies between the modules containing both enums (a 2-way conversion would require the DTO module to know about the other enum AND vice-versa). Another (smaller) advantage is that the extension can live in another package or file with a more limited visibility, so only the "conversion" code knows about it. This limits clutter in auto-complete and the likes.

Answer (score 0):

You could also make a simpler function (like @Ivo's function):

```
fun toPilotType(p: PilotTypeDTO): PilotType {
  return when(p) {
     // Add edge cases 
     // example
     PilotTypeDTO.SOME_NON_MATCHING_PILOT -> PilotType.BACKEND_VERSION_OF_THIS_PILOT
     // Those with the same name will be handled here
     else -> PilotType.valueOf(p.name)
  }
}
```

This way you can extend the enums without needing to update the when statement every time